# How would I reduce this array so the objects in each are merged javascript but dont know key value names

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I have an array within an array that I want to reduce the subarrays such that they are one object within. Here is the code generating the array

```js
const final = data.formEntryData.map((item) => {
    //console.log(Object.keys(item.data));
    let key = Object.values(item.data);
    let test = data.hmm.map((array) => {
      //console.log(array.arrayOrder);
      return { [array.name]: key[array.arrayOrder] };
    });
    return test;
  });
```

Here is the array within array

```js
[
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'fdsafa' },
    { 'Product Description': 'ffdsafa' },
    { 'Product Image': 'fdasf' },
    { 'Product Price': undefined },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': undefined }
  ],
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'Roasted Beans' },
    { 'Product Description': 'For the Squire' },
    { 'Product Image': 'http://image.com' },
    { 'Product Price': undefined },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': undefined }
  ],
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'Shoes' },
    { 'Product Description': 'Worn' },
    { 'Product Image': 'google.com' },
    { 'Product Price': '100' },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': undefined }
  ],
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'fdsajkl' },
    { 'Product Description': 'klfdlsk' },
    { 'Product Image': 'flkdsjl' },
    { 'Product Price': 'flskj' },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': 'lkjfsdlk' }
  ],
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'shoes' },
    { 'Product Description': 'very good' },
    { 'Product Image': 'image.com' },
    { 'Product Price': '20' },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': 'yes' }
  ],
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'fdsaf' },
    { 'Product Description': 'fdsa' },
    { 'Product Image': 'fdsa' },
    { 'Product Price': 'fdsa' },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': 'fdsa' }
  ],
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'fdskj' },
    { 'Product Description': '291898868491092489' },
    { 'Product Image': 'fsdk' },
    { 'Product Price': '291898998629859848' },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': 'fsd;lk' }
  ],
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'fdsfa' },
    { 'Product Description': 'fdsaf' },
    { 'Product Image': 'fdsafa' },
    { 'Product Price': 'fdsaf' },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': 'fdasf' }
  ],
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'ds' },
    { 'Product Description': 'fdsa' },
    { 'Product Image': 'fdsa' },
    { 'Product Price': 'fdsa' },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': 'fdsa' }
  ],
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'fdsfds' },
    { 'Product Description': 'fdsfafds' },
    { 'Product Image': 'fdsafs' },
    { 'Product Price': 'fdsaf' },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': 'fdsaf' }
  ],
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'fdsfds' },
    { 'Product Description': 'fdsfafds' },
    { 'Product Image': 'fdsafs' },
    { 'Product Price': 'fdsaf' },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': 'fdsaf' }
  ],
  [
    { 'Product Title Test': 'fdsaf' },
    { 'Product Description': 'fdsafs' },
    { 'Product Image': 'fdasfd' },
    { 'Product Price': 'fdasfdsa' },
    { 'Live on Website Test two Three': 'fdasfd' }
  ]
]
```

I want to `merge the subarrays` so one would look like this

```js
[
[...],
[
    { 'Product Title Test': 'fdsaf',
    'Product Description': 'fdsafs',
    'Product Image': 'fdasfd',
    'Product Price': 'fdasfdsa',
    'Live on Website Test two Three': 'fdasfd' }
  ]
,
[...]
]
```

I have looked at reduce like this

```js
var arr = [{key:"11", value:"1100"},{key:"22", value:"2200"}];
var object = final.reduce(
  (obj, item,) => Object.assign(obj, { [item.key]: item.value }), {});

console.log(object)
```

However I don't know the `item.key` and `.item.value` names because they are derived in the map function.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question to use less input data but give us a complete matching output.  What is the [...] array in output for instance?  To me the input and output as far as the question goes looks the same, so I cannot tell what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the array you provided, you can merge the nested arrays into objects using the following function, which uses `Object.entries` to access the properties for each of the objects.

```
function mergeInner(outer) {
  return outer.map(inner =>
    inner.reduce((merged, obj) => {
      Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        merged[k] = v;
      });
      return merged;
    }, {})
  );
}
```

Which produces:

```
[
  {
    'Product Title Test': 'fdsafa',
    'Product Description': 'ffdsafa',
    'Product Image': 'fdasf',
    'Product Price': undefined,
    'Live on Website Test two Three': undefined
  },
  {
    'Product Title Test': 'Roasted Beans',
    'Product Description': 'For the Squire',
    'Product Image': 'http://image.com',
    'Product Price': undefined,
    'Live on Website Test two Three': undefined
  },
  ...
}
```